# Ruby BCrypt returning numbers

Tags: ruby, encryption, bcrypt

I am using BCrypt in my RoR and I am getting numbers instead of the hexadecimal representation I am used to.  Here is the criminal code.

```
username = params[:username]
password = params[:password]

encrypted_password = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
encrypted_password = encrypted_password.hash
```

the encrypted_password variable comes out as numbers like 4245597694343378249.  I've used BCrypt for Java and I am was expecting something like $2asfa$asdfasfsafsad.  I was wondering if anyone knew  what I am doing wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a note, calling it "encrypted" isn't really correct, it's hashed.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Thanks Andrew, I don't quite know the difference.  I guess the colloquial difference is that encryption is 2 way with the intent of obscuring information and then later converting it back to plaintext, whereas a hash is just a one-way,unique function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password variable coming out as a sequence of numbers is because of the .hash you are applying to the encrypted password. So you are calling the String#hash method which just gives you a hash based on the length and contents.

If you want to see the bcrypt output that you are expecting just do the following:

```
username = params[:username]
password = params[:password]

encrypted_password = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
puts encrypted_password
```

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: Thanks Sean, that was it.  For some reason the BCrypt implementation in Ruby seems to involve a tad bit more magic than I am accustomed to.  Do you mind telling me an instance in which one would use the string has of the password hash ?

Comment: I've never had a practical use to be honest. The only thing I could thing to use it for would be comparisons... Storing thousands of strings as their .hash and then checking for equality would seem to be less work than the strings themselves.